# What will adapter.getItem() return?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have created a custom array adapter for my custom ListView, which has TextViews and a Checkbox. In my customadapter I created a method called isChecked() -

```
    static class personHolder
    {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtNumber;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        public boolean isChecked(){
            boolean isChecked_boolean = false; ///this holds the return value, of whether the checkbox is checked or not.
            if(checkbox.isChecked()){
                isChecked_boolean = true;
            }
            else{
                isChecked_boolean = false;
            }
            return isChecked_boolean;
        }
    }
}
```

OK. I know use a loop that iterates through my view like so:

```
public ArrayList<PeopleDetails> checkbox_SMS(ListAdapter adapter){
    ArrayList<PeopleDetails> people_SMS = new ArrayList<PeopleDetails>();
    for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
        if(((personHolder) adapter.getItem(i)).isChecked() == true){
            people_SMS.add((PeopleDetails) people_details.toArray()[i]);
            ///adds the corresponing people_details item to the arraylist of PeopleDetails, to send SMS messages to.
        }
    }
    return people_SMS; ///returns the list.

}
```

However I get an error at the line if(((personHolder) adapter.getItem(i)).isChecked() == true) saying that it cannot cast from PeopleDetails to personHolder. PeopleDetails is the type that I pass to my customadapter for the data in the TextViews. What have I done wrong?

QUESTION - What should that line be to properly get the result I want? Thanks for the help!!

```
package com.example.partyorganiser;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class peoplelist_customadapter extends ArrayAdapter<PeopleDetails>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    ArrayList<PeopleDetails> data = null;

    public peoplelist_customadapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<PeopleDetails> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        personHolder holder = null;
        PeopleDetails[] people_array = data.toArray(new PeopleDetails[data.size()]);


        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new personHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);
            holder.txtNumber = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.number_txt);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (personHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        PeopleDetails person = people_array[position];
        holder.txtName.setText(person.name);
        holder.txtNumber.setText(person.number);

        ///CheckBox mCheckBox = (CheckBox) mView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);


        return row;
    }
    public boolean getView_IsChecked(int position){

    }



    static class personHolder
    {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtNumber;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        public boolean isChecked(){
            boolean isChecked_boolean = false; ///this holds the return value, of whether the checkbox is checked or not.
            if(checkbox.isChecked()){
                isChecked_boolean = true;
            }
            else{
                isChecked_boolean = false;
            }
            return isChecked_boolean;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your adapter? getItem() should return whatever you implement it to return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put the logic of determining whether or not check the checkbox inside your `getView()` override.

You should not use the `personHolder` class anywhere outside the adapter - it is for it's use only in recycling views.

Comment: getView() returns a view normally though, whereas I would want a boolean. I thought getView() was used in inflating my ListView.

Comment: The view will be checked or not depending on what is in your PeopleDetails class, is that right? In which case you just call getItem() to get the PeopleDetails and you know by the same logic whether the checkbox is checked. If the user can toggle the checkbox that is a different question.

Comment: the user will toggle the checkbox. What is the easiest way to get whether it is checked, and then add it to a seperate arraylist?? I want to take the items that are checked, and add them to a seperate arraylist, and ignore the others.

Comment: Inside of `getView` add a click handler for the checkbox. When the checkbox is clicked, update the underlying PeopleDetails object. Then you can loop through your data to get the clicked items. You do not want to attempt to loop through all your views - they may not all exist at the same time.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot!! That explains what my problem is!! :)